# Handling SRP Auth and Generating Device Key (PHP - Server side)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, key, device, amazon-cognito

I've implemented in my backend Cognito with Signup and Login, MFA activation and inactivation, but now I want to implement the remember devices, to reduce SMS confirmation.

For that, I've adjusted the InitiateAuth Function to the following code:

```
$client->initiateAuth([
'AuthFlow' => 'USER_SRP_AUTH', // REQUIRED
'AuthParameters' => [
"USERNAME" => $email,
"PASSWORD" => $password,
"SRP_A" => $bigA,
],
'ClientId' => $this->getClientId(), // REQUIRED
]);
```

This function runs properly, and returns the code in following image:

https://i.gyazo.com/a439e48e2de85a094f56ed4cfee10f83.png

Then, I continue generating SRP Values, and call in the function respondToAuthChallenge, with the following code:

```
$client->respondToAuthChallenge([
'ChallengeName' => 'DEVICE_SRP_AUTH',
'ChallengeResponses' => [
'USERNAME' => $username,
'SRP_A' => $bigA,
],
'ClientId' => $this->getClientId(),
]);
```

Yet, It returns me an error saying: 'Missing required parameter DEVICE_KEY'.

If I put a DEVICE_KEY key inside ChallengeResponses it starts returning me the error 'Device does not exist.'

I've searched a lot and cannot find a way to generate the DEVICE_KEY. I've tried with unique ID and sending it in both initiateAuthand respondToAuthChallenge but the error is the same.

Any clue how can I do it? I Believe that SRP code is not 100% yet, as still understanding the concept, yet, cannot understand the DEVICE_KEY part.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Cafn I am also facing this. Did you already resolve this?

Comment: Also Cafn, How did you generate $bigA (SRP_A value) using PHP?

Comment: Hi @VivekPipaliya. Sadly cannot remember well since I no longer work on the company and don't remember what I did at that time. What I remember that I've did was to check the documentation (weak spot from aws) and check If i was doing everything right. Also, I believe that I wasn't doing the requests in proper order (basicly, you use the response from one in another). Good luck with this problem, sorry for not helping more. Check this one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use [Server Side Authentication Flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-server-side-authentication-flow)

For server-side apps, user pool authentication is similar to that for client-side apps, except:

- The server-side app calls the `AdminInitiateAuth` API (instead of `InitiateAuth`). This method requires AWS admin credentials. This method returns the authentication parameters.
- Once it has the authentication parameters, the app calls the `AdminRespondToAuthChallenge` API (instead of `RespondToAuthChallenge`), which also requires AWS admin credentials.

The [`AdminInitiateAuth`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference//API_AdminInitiateAuth.html) returns among other stuff the device key.

Comment: Can we use "Remembering Device" functionality by using AdminInitiateAuth too?